# Problema con bucle while junto con condiciones if

Tags: java, consola, condiciones

Tengo un problema que yo creo que cualquier programador intermedio lo puede solucionar. El caso es que tengo un bucle while en el que si pongo en el input (por ejemplo) "suma" y añado los números se realiza la resta pero después vuelve a ejecutarse el while y sale como si hubiera puesto después nada en el input y me sale el error (y después, obviamente, se vuelve a ejecutar).

Código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\tCalculadora");
        System.out.println("--------------------------");


        int condicion = 1;
        while(condicion == 1){

            System.out.println("¿Qué operación desea realizar?");
            System.out.println("Suma");
            System.out.println("Resta");
            System.out.println("Salir");

            String operacion = scan.nextLine();

            if(operacion.toLowerCase().equals("suma")){
                System.out.println("Introduce los números que quieres sumar");

                System.out.println("Número 1: ");
                double numero1 = scan.nextDouble();

                System.out.println("Número 2: ");
                double numero2 = scan.nextDouble();

                Suma suma = new Suma(numero1, numero2);

                System.out.println("Resultado: " + suma.getSuma());

            }else if(operacion.toLowerCase().equals("resta")){
                System.out.println("Introduce los números que quieres restar");

                System.out.println("Número 1: ");
                double numero1 = scan.nextDouble();

                System.out.println("Número 2: ");
                double numero2 = scan.nextDouble();


                Resta resta = new Resta(numero1, numero2);

                System.out.println("Resultado: " + resta.getResta());

            }else if(operacion.toLowerCase().equals("salir")){
                System.out.println("¡Adiós! ;)");
                condicion = 0;


            }else{
                System.out.println("Error: Puede ser que hayas escrito mal la palabra. Vuelve a intentarlo");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Por consola:

```
        Calculadora
--------------------------
¿Qué operación desea realizar?
Suma
Resta
Salir
SUMA (input)
Introduce los números que quieres sumar
Número 1: 
1 (input)
Número 2: 
1 (input)
Resultado: 2.0
¿Qué operación desea realizar?
Suma
Resta
Salir
Error: Puede ser que hayas escrito mal la palabra. Vuelve a intentarlo
¿Qué operación desea realizar?
Suma
Resta
Salir
```

Si necesitáis las otras dos clases os las envio, pero creo que no hace falta, por eso no las añado.

¡Saludos! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema de que se ejecute otra ves y salga ese mensaje de error, es debido a que estas usando el método `nextDouble` y este solo captura el valor que requieren, en cambio `nextLine` necesita un salto de linea para acabar y como esta en un bucle se salta porque antes se ha usado `nextDouble`.

Usando tu código debería quedar así:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\tCalculadora");
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    int condicion = 1;
    while(condicion == 1){
        System.out.println("¿Qué operación desea realizar?");
        System.out.println("Suma");
        System.out.println("Resta");
        System.out.println("Salir");
        String operacion = scan.nextLine();
        if(operacion.toLowerCase().equals("suma")){
            System.out.println("Introduce los números que quieres sumar");
            System.out.println("Número 1: ");
            double numero1 = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Número 2: ");
            double numero2 = scan.nextDouble();
            Suma suma = new Suma(numero1, numero2);
            System.out.println("Resultado: " + suma.getSuma());
            scan.nextLine();
        }else if(operacion.toLowerCase().equals("resta")){
            System.out.println("Introduce los números que quieres restar");
            System.out.println("Número 1: ");
            double numero1 = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Número 2: ");
            double numero2 = scan.nextDouble();
            Resta resta = new Resta(numero1, numero2);
            System.out.println("Resultado: " + resta.getResta());
            scan.nextLine();
        }else if(operacion.toLowerCase().equals("salir")){
            System.out.println("¡Adiós! ;)");
            condicion = 0;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Error: Puede ser que hayas escrito mal la palabra. Vuelve a intentarlo");
        }
    }

}
```

Pero te recomiendo usar `next()` en este caso porque tu solo ingresar un texto sin espacios.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\tCalculadora");
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    int condicion = 1;
    while(condicion == 1){
        System.out.println("¿Qué operación desea realizar?");
        System.out.println("Suma");
        System.out.println("Resta");
        System.out.println("Salir");
        String operacion = scan.next();
        if(operacion.toLowerCase().equals("suma")){
            System.out.println("Introduce los números que quieres sumar");
            System.out.println("Número 1: ");
            double numero1 = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Número 2: ");
            double numero2 = scan.nextDouble();
            Suma suma = new Suma(numero1, numero2);
            System.out.println("Resultado: " + suma.getSuma());
        }else if(operacion.toLowerCase().equals("resta")){
            System.out.println("Introduce los números que quieres restar");
            System.out.println("Número 1: ");
            double numero1 = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Número 2: ");
            double numero2 = scan.nextDouble();
            Resta resta = new Resta(numero1, numero2);
            System.out.println("Resultado: " + resta.getResta());
        }else if(operacion.toLowerCase().equals("salir")){
            System.out.println("¡Adiós! ;)");
            condicion = 0;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Error: Puede ser que hayas escrito mal la palabra. Vuelve a intentarlo");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Realmente esta es la unica respuesta que se enfoca en el problema. ¡Bienvenido a Stackoverflow!

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Pero una pregunta, ¿porque añades throws Exception? Yo lo he quitado y se soluciona igual el problema

Comment: Hola @Runforyourlife el throws Exception solo funcionará cuando se produzca una excepción en tu código.

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo que las operaciones las cambies la libreria Scanner por BufferedReader

La diferencia entre los dos, es que Scanner es mas rapido de utilizar, pero BufferedReader es mas preciso al momento de capturar datos.

Answer (score 0):

`do while` sería más adecuado:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\tCalculadora");
        System.out.println("--------------------------");


        int condicion = 1;
        do{

            System.out.println("¿Qué operación desea realizar?");
            System.out.println("Suma");
            System.out.println("Resta");
            System.out.println("Salir");

            String operacion = scan.nextLine();

            if(operacion.toLowerCase().equals("suma")){
                System.out.println("Introduce los números que quieres sumar");

                System.out.println("Número 1: ");
                double numero1 = scan.nextDouble();

                System.out.println("Número 2: ");
                double numero2 = scan.nextDouble();

                Suma suma = new Suma(numero1, numero2);

                System.out.println("Resultado: " + suma.getSuma());

            }else if(operacion.toLowerCase().equals("resta")){
                System.out.println("Introduce los números que quieres restar");

                System.out.println("Número 1: ");
                double numero1 = scan.nextDouble();

                System.out.println("Número 2: ");
                double numero2 = scan.nextDouble();


                Resta resta = new Resta(numero1, numero2);

                System.out.println("Resultado: " + resta.getResta());

            }else if(operacion.toLowerCase().equals("salir")){
                   System.out.println("¡Adiós! ;)");
                   condicion = 0;

            }else{
                System.out.println("Error: Puede ser que hayas escrito mal la palabra. Vuelve a intentarlo");
            }
        } while(condicion == 1)
    }
}
```

**Nota**: Sería recomendable usar `case` en lugar de `if.. else`.

Comment: No tengo un penúltimo else, es un else if

Comment: Seguramente tendrás razón, pero no me soluciona el problema ;(